# exported retargeted animation is only 24 keyframes long (scene is set to 34 keyframes and animation is 34 keyframes long)

Tags: animation, export, keyframes, baking, .fbx

So I've been retargeting animations with the Rokoko add-on and things are perfect in my blender scene. The first was 24 keyframes long, exported as 24 keyframes. The second was 251 keyframes, exported as 24, for an hour straight of trying different solutions I finally got it to bake at 251 frames into an animated .FBX file. I assumed the problem was that my source retarget armature (the armature that my constraints are set to) was hidden from the viewport (not disabled just hidden [image] like so).

Thinking I had solved the issue, I tried to do another animation with 34 keyframes but even with the source armatures visible, it would still export at 24 keyframes. I've tried to bake the animation before exporting (even though the exporting process does it for you), and still no luck.

My export settings for animated FBXs are as so (copied directly from this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ysl0qYq5p9w&t=1s)):

[image]
[image]

I included a list of 3 files [here](https://humberital-my.sharepoint.com/:f:/g/personal/n01394324_humber_ca/EjELw0REajJPn7U-lI4TJPoBE_qNbyjq-tz_dYz7SDlMAg?e=BttkHw), the one called `secre_jump_fbx2.blend` is the one that only exports 24 of the 34 frames. `secre_jump_exported_fbx.blend` is the failed result of the exported FBX and `secre_idle_fbx_EXAMPLE.blend` is the 251 keyframe animation (pre-export) that works (to possibly see *why* it works). The animation is baked on that one but it didn't seem to make a difference on my jump file.

And here is a glance at my viewport in-case you notice anything wrong off the bat.

[image]

I am exporting the animated FBX of `metarig.001`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what's causing this to work, but if i bake a new animation with the skeleton (output properties and such set to desired frame length, it will create a new animation. If i go into the NLA editor, push down the action as an NLA strip,

[image]

then head over to the action clip section in the N menu, select my newly baked clip,

[image]

go to the outliner and select all other animations labelled "action", except for your baked clip,
[image]

it will work. I must be creating some sort of workaround here, but at least it does work.